# Json Schema Validation for entire folder in Visual Studio Solution

Tags: json, visual-studio, yaml, jsonschema

I am trying to get Visual Studio (IDE, not Code) to validate yaml or at least json files.
The following folder structure is used:

```
|   MySolution.sln
|   
\---MyProject
    |   MyProject.sqlproj
    |   MyProject.sqlproj.user     
    +---JsonSchema
    |       DataSchema.json     
    +---YamlData
    |       A.yml
    |       B.yml   
    \---JsonData
            C.json
            D.json
```

Now the DataSchema can validate the json files if the user manually adds the `$schema` property or sets the schema in the dropdown above. For yaml, this does not work at all.

In the end, I want all files in YamlData/JsonData to be automatically validated using a specific schema from the JsonSchema folder without the user/other developers having to recall that they need to add that schema reference.